# Parsing Java Class From Perl or Python

Tags: java, python, perl, parsing

I want to get a .java file, recognize the first class in the file, and get information about annotations, methods and attributes from this class.

Is there any module in both languages that already does that?
I could build up a simple regexp to do it also, but I don't known how to recognize in the regexp the braces indicating the end of the class/method.

Comment: No, regex is not suited for this. Consider `class Foo { String s = "not an @Annotation here"; }`.

Comment: Ok, so I would have to use a grammar or an automata to do it. Is there any perl/python module that could help me do this sort of thing?

Comment: @Bart Actually you could regex to not consider thing in double quotes. The problem is with braces, once you can't really count how many opening and closing braces happened so far in a regex.

Comment: @Samuel, sure. Note that I didn't say one couldn't use regex. I said regex isn't suited for such a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the java classes inside [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) you probably could use introspection to find the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying this in perl/python rather than just using a javadoc-aware program that can pull out the info?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **[Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/~patl/Inline-Java-0.52/Java.pod)** for **accessing Java class from Perl**,Once you have that interface running, you can easily access methods and attributes from the class.