# Way to run Maven from Python script?

Tags: python, maven, batch-file

*(I am using Windows.)*

I am trying to run maven from a python script. I have this:

```py
import subprocess

mvn="C:\\_home\\apache-maven-2.2.1\\bin\\mvn.bat --version"
p = subprocess.Popen(mvn, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print p.returncode # is 0 if success
```

It works fine, but I am wondering about the following:

- Better ways to add parameters instead of appending the string.
- Maybe some specific way to run maven without the above.
- A way to show the output (currently it only prints a 1 or 0 based on failure/success).

---

What I am trying to accomplish long term (I note this in case someone has a better method) is to make a simple script to build a list of projects and move  another list of files (jars/other modified things) to a folder to deploy to VMs, it's a huge pain to do manually. I have this working in a batch script no sweat, I am just curious to learn Python and wonder if it'd be easier to manage because I could just make a couple of lists and iterate over each of the locations rather than have a line for each task in the batch script.

*(Short version of what my batch script looks like.)*

```
@set version=7.8.3
@set staging_folder=C:\Users\me\Desktop\staging

@set stage_was=%staging_folder%\was
@set stage_ear=%stage_was%\stuffui.ear
@set stage_war=%stage_ear%\stuff-%version%.war

:: delete stage contents
call del /s /q %staging_folder%
call rmdir /s /q %stage_was%

:: make folders
call mkdir %stage_ear%
call mkdir %stage_war%\WEB-INF\lib

:: maven builds
call mvn -f C:\workspace\pom.xml -pl proj1,proj2 clean install

:: copy to stage
call xcopy C:\workspace\proj1\target\thing1.jar %stage_ear%\ /i /y

call xcopy C:\workspace\proj2\target\thing2.jar %stage_ear%\ /i /y
call xcopy C:\workspace\proj2\target\thing2.jar %stage_war%\WEB-INF\lib\ /i /y
```

Comment: try like this `call mvn -f C:\workspace\pom.xml -pl "proj1,proj2" clean install`

Comment: My batch-script is working as-is, I am trying to make something similar in Python.

Comment: I think it is important to tell maven to run in batch mode (so it uses defaults and does not prompt for input): mvn --batch-mode -v

Comment: @wemu It better should be `-V` instead of `-v`. See _Maven: The Complete Reference, 6.1.4. Displaying Version Information:_ [_"the `-v` option will terminate the Maven process after printing out the version."_](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-version-option)"_

Comment: true. just wanted to emphasize the batch mode - and messed up the -v (which does not the same thing as -V) - very true  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Apache Maven Invoker API](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/index.html).

[Mark's answer to *Accessing Java API information with Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293930/1744774) mentions:

> *[Jython](http://www.jython.org/) which is Python run on the Java VM.*

See [my answers there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787395/1744774) for an example on how to use the Maven Invoker (from within Java in this particular case).

Comment: I am trying to clarify, this Apache Maven Invoker API is java, so you suggest I use Jython to take advantage of it through JVM while still technically using/learning Python, right?

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> *in case someone has a better method*

Re:

> *move another list of files (jars/other modified things) to a folder*

Have you considered using Maven itself (the `copy-resources` goal of its [Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) in this particular case)?

Re:

> *I am just curious to learn Python*

Since you are working with Java anyway: Have you considered [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as the scripting language of your choice?

Some of its advantages:

- The Java language is a subset of the Groovy language. I.e. every Java code is also Groovy code. You don't have to use the full-fledged Groovy syntax from the beginning while learning it.
- It can be scripted.
- It is supported as scripting and [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) in tools like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will pass on copy-resources as I don't want to fool with pom files if I don't have too and as far as Groovy vs Python it would just raise the same question: "how do I invoke maven through Groovy"

Comment: @CaptainMan _"how do I invoke maven through Groovy"_ – via the Maven Invoker API mentioned in my other answer here.