# Maven command mvn runs without errors from terminal but not from python

Tags: java, python-3.x, shell, maven, subprocess

I am trying to run a maven project from a python script. I have installed apache maven. 
Running the command: `mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="org.matsim.project.RunMatsim"` from terminal in the project folder where the pom.xml is, creates no errors and the project runs correctly.

But when running the following code from my python script

```
import subprocess as sp

def execute(cmd):
    popen = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True,shell=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line 
    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise sp.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)

for path in execute(["mvn", "exec:java" ,'-D"exec.mainClass"="org.matsim.project.MatsimRun"']):
    print(path, end="")
```

I got the following error:

[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify`

Why this is the case? What could be wrong?

The occurred warnings are the same for both cases (terminal, python script).

Comment: Running the same command with R `system('mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="org.matsim.project.RunMatsim"')` works fine, if this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally when I run into issues with args when running a program from java/python/etc. I wrap the command I want to use in an `sh -c`, like so:

```py
sp.Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', "mvn exec:java -D\"exec.mainClass\"=\"org.matsim.project.MatsimRun\""])
```

The above seems to work properly for me. Please be aware there may be security implications of doing this, make sure that the command entered as the third parameter of `sh` is never hooked up to the internet of hate.

Okay so now why was your code not working?

The python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) say that `shell=True` is equivalent to:

```
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
```

So a good hypothesis is that `sh` is ignoring `arg[1]` and further arguments. 
You can test this by doing:

```
<censored>@debian:~$ sh -c echo "sfaklg"

<censored>@debian:~$
```

Observe how `echo` doesn't get the args it expects. This consistent across many different quoting methods/shells:

```
<censored>@debian:~$ dash -c echo "sfaklg"

<censored>@debian:~$ bash -c echo "sfaklg"

<censored>@debian:~$ zsh -c echo "sfaklg"

<censored>@debian:~$ zsh -c echo sfaklg

<censored>@debian:~$ bash -c echo sfaklg

<censored>@debian:~$
```

The man page for bash says:

> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

In other words `sh -c` is intended for running shell scripts which expect args to be passed with `$1` , `$2`, ... .

So what should you do?

Is suspect you want to run maven in a shell because it needs `JAVA_HOME` or similar environment vars to be set. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment) gives examples of how to set/modify the environment vars, though you may still need `shell=True`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39362418/3424746) also suggests using the env command to override environment variables.

Lastly you may find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945161/way-to-run-maven-from-python-script) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the double quotes surrounding `exec.mainClass`, ie:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.matsim.project.MatsimRun"
```

instead of:

```
mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="org.matsim.project.MatsimRun"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the below line

```
["mvn", "exec:java" ,'-D"exec.mainClass"="org.matsim.project.MatsimRun"']
```

with

```
["mvn", "exec:java" ,"-D\"exec.mainClass\"=\"org.matsim.project.MatsimRun\""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think one of the biggest problems facing programmers who code in different programming environments is the use of double-quotes `("")` and single-quotes `('')`, which can cause annoying issues like yours.

To deal with, you can use plugins rather than consuming the built-in commands of maven. Add the following plugin to your `pom.xml` file and then execute your application far easier.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>org.matsim.project.MatsimRun</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the above-mentioned plugin, it is assumed that your `Main` class is `org.matsim.project.MatsimRun`. To trigger the plugin from the command-line, just run:

```
mvn exec:java
```

I hope this helps!